# Migrating from IdentityServer3 to Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, identityserver3

We have an identity server that uses IdentityServer3 with ASP.NET Identity as the User Store. This is used by an AngularJS SPA app, mobile apps (Android and Windows) to access a web service built using ASP.NET Web API v2. This is a consumer facing application where users registers themselves and logs in to use our services.

With Azure Active Directory B2C in preview, we plan to migrate to it in the near future. This is because we have a very small team and therefore we want to focus on our core application and outsource other services, i.e. the aforementioned.

Can you help with pointers and best practices on how to migrate our users.

Comment: You'd have to ask Microsoft about this. I'm surprised they don't have docs for it.

Comment: Did you ever find any docs or get any help from Microsoft on this? I'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: @Ryan, No not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Quick update on this. There is support for migrating accounts with hashed passwords. Essentially, Azure AD B2C makes a call to your API to validate credentials and then B2C stores the credentials since it already has the plaintext password.

[Azure AD B2C Migration](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration)

Answer (score 0):

1. Azure AD B2C has Graph API, using by which you can easily migrate the users from the Users Table.
2. If the users password is hashed (in most cases) then there might be a problem migrating the users, you need look for the option to unhash the password, before migration.
3. If you are not able to unhash the password before migration, you can provide an option to user who can recover the user password, meantime you can create the user using Graph API - in - Azure AD B2C.

Hope it helps. You will find details & code sample in the below link.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

Comment: I thought of something along those lines and the biggest problem is the one you mentioned at 2, hashed passwords. When the time comes we will explore how to implement your part 3 suggestion in a more user friendly manner, and thank you.